# MongoDB Remove Empty Object from Array after aggregate function

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

The output of the db.name.aggregate() function gives output:

```json
[{}, {"abc": "zyx"}, {}, "opk": "tyr"]
```

Actual output desired :

```json
[{"abc": "zyx"}, "opk": "tyr"]
```

Comment: Are you sure is this the correct data returned? It is not the correct format for BSON.

Comment: If you show the full, or pertinent parts of the, aggregation pipeline, I'm confident someone will offer an option to produce the output you want.

Comment: This is a invalid array.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your output is not a valid array. It should be like this:

```
[{}, {"abc": "zyx"}, {}, {"opk": "tyr"}]
```

Now, to obtain your desired output, you can add the following `$match` stage, to
your pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here, we are converting the document to an array using `$objectToArray`, and then we check whether the size of that array is greater than 0. Only those documents are kept in the output.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NeHVgINHcUM)

Answer (score 1):

What if you data looks like this.

```json
[
  {
    "arr": [
      {},
      {
        "abc": "zyx"
      },
      {},
      {
        "opk": "tyr"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The aggregation be like this to remove empty objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$arr",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      arr: {
        "$ne": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$_id",
      arr: {
        $push: "$arr"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

`Outputs`

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "arr": [
      {
        "abc": "zyx"
      },
      {
        "opk": "tyr"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo@mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BjGxzlrlj6s)

https://mongoplayground.net/p/BjGxzlrlj6s